# The map doesn't show changes over time

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using mapbox gl js in order to create a map to show the number of accidents across the Europe. My code looks exact the same as here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/timeline-animation/

But mine doesn't show the changes over time. On console there is no error. Does anybody know why?

The link for the code is here: https://jsbin.com/kelolapafa/edit?html,css,js,output

```
document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('input', function(e){
var iyear = parseInt(e.target.value);
filterBy(iyear);
  map.setPaintProperty('terror7-circles', 'circle-radius', {
                'property': 'map',
                'stops':[
                [6, 14],
                    [8, 20]
                ]
              });
  map.setPaintProperty('terror7-circles', 'circle-color', 'blue');
  map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layer: ['terror7-circles'], includeGeometry: true });
  map.setLayoutProperty('terror7-circles', 'visibility')
  });
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code seems messed up and doesn't run at all. You have a "<script>" tag in your javascript section on the JSBin...